# Spark SQL: Create constant value based on column in other table

Tags: sql, case, self-join, coalesce, derived-column

I have two tables:
(1) Line

```
| ID  | Client | 
| --- | ------ | 
| 0001| 0001   |  
| 0001| 0002   |  
| 0001| 0003   |
```

Line holds all available clients for a specific ID (there can be more IDs) and is the base table. Shipping is a derived field taken from Line_Update table (Shipping_ID field). Whenever the Client is mentioned in the Line_Update table, then Shipping value must be taken from Line_Update col:Shipping_ID. If the Client from Line table is not mentioned in Line_Update then the Shipping_ID value that belongs to Client=0000 (Line_Update table) must be assigned to the Shipping field in Line table.

- So e.g. Client:0001 is not in the Line_Update table and therefore gets assigned the Shipping value for Client=0000 from Line_update.

(2) Line_update

```
| ID  | Client | Shipping_ID  |
| --- |  ------|--------------|
| 0001|   0000 |  01234       |
| 0001|  0002  |  01222       |
```

Line_update holds some order lines from Line table that need to overwrite the Line value whenever the Line ID is there in the Line_Update table.

(3) Expected Table

```
| ID  | Client | Shipping |
| --- | ------ | ---------|
| 0001| 0001   |   01234  |
| 0001| 0002   |   01222  |
| 0001| 0003   |   01234  |
```

**My question.**

Does anyone know how I can create a new column in Line_update that will store the value from Shipping where ID=0000 in Line table in a new column as constant value?

What my idea was, was to use coalesce function and perform the logic that if the client is in Line_Update table then take the Shipping_ID. If it is not in Line_Update take the Shipping_ID value where Client = 0000.

Comment: Sample data is fine, but you also need to _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: Updated question to reflect updated result.

Comment: Don't add a column for one value: you'll be duplicating, add a row with client 0000, based on id 0000 if need be